# Sort a match group by id in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

(Mongo newbie here, sorry) I have a mongodb collection, result of a mapreduce with this schema :

```
{
  "_id" : "John Snow",
  "value" : {
    "countTot" : 500,
    "countCall" : 30,
    "comment" : [
      {
        "text" : "this is a text",
        "date" : 2016-11-17 00:00:00.000Z,
        "type" : "call"
      },
      {
        "text" : "this is a text",
        "date" : 2016-11-12 00:00:00.000Z,
        "type" : "visit"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

My goal is to have a document containing all the comments of a certain type. For example, a document John snow with all the calls.

I manage to have all the comments for a certain type using this :

```
db.general_stats.aggregate(

    { $unwind: '$value.comment' },

    { $match: {
        'value.comment.type': 'call'
    }}
)
```

However, I can't find a way to group the data received by the ID (for example john snow) even using the $group property. Any idea ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your query.

```
    db.getCollection('calls').aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$value.comment' },
    { $match: {
        'value.comment.type': 'call'
    }},
    { 
        $group : {
            _id : "$_id",
            comment : { $push : "$value.comment"},
            countTot : {$first : "$value.countTot"},
            countCall : {$first : "$value.countCall"},
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 1,
            value : {"countTot":"$countTot","countCall":"$countCall","comment":"$comment"}
        }
    }
])
```

or either you can go with **$project** with **$filter** option

```
db.getCollection('calls').aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
         "value.comment": {
            $filter: {
               input: "$value.comment",
               as: "comment",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$comment.type", 'call' ] }
            }
         },
         "value.countTot":"$value.countTot",
         "value.countCall":"$value.countCall",
      }
   }
])
```

In both case below is my output.

```
{
    "_id" : "John Snow",
    "value" : {
        "countTot" : 500,
        "countCall" : 30,
        "comment" : [ 
            {
                "text" : "this is a text",
                "date" : "2016-11-17 00:00:00.000Z",
                "type" : "call"
            }, 
            {
                "text" : "this is a text 2",
                "date" : "2016-11-17 00:00:00.000Z",
                "type" : "call"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query which is the extension of the one present in OP.

```
db.general_stats.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$value.comment' },
    { $match: {
        'value.comment.type': 'call'
    }},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", allValues : {"$push" : "$$ROOT"}}},
    {$project : {"allValues" : 1, _id : 0} },
    {$unwind : "$allValues" }
);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "allValues" : {
        "_id" : "John Snow",
        "value" : {
            "countTot" : 500,
            "countCall" : 30,
            "comment" : {
                "text" : "this is a text",
                "date" : ISODate("2016-11-25T10:46:49.258Z"),
                "type" : "call"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer looking at this :

[How to retrieve all matching elements present inside array in Mongo DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429243/how-to-retrieve-all-matching-elements-present-inside-array-in-mongo-db)

using the $addToSet property in the $group one.