# How to use projection with $or which using multiple conditions based on object in an array

Tags: mongodb

this is a sample document

```
{
"userId": {
    "$oid": "613c1447259f38c65bb9a55b"
},
"companyId": {
    "$oid": "613c1448259f38c65bb9a55d"
},
"startDate": {
    "$date": "2021-09-20T00:00:00.000Z"
},
"timeSlot": [{
    "startTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T07:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6148a6a1bb84ebf378ce09c4"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T10:00:00.000Z"
    }
}, {
    "startTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T07:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6148a6adbb84ebf378ce09c5"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T09:00:00.000Z"
    }
}, {
    "startTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T07:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-20T10:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6148af71bb84ebf378ce09c6"
    }
}],
"__v": 0
```

}

and this is the following query

```
{$or:[{"timeSlot.startTime":{$lt: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gt: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endDate":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }]}
```

which is looking for conflicting time slots for the given date times. i.e if any time slots having times which messes with the given dates, then it finds the document.

but i also want to know what timeSlot(s) aka objects in timeSlot array which is matching with this $or query?.

i tried

```
{"timeSlot.$": 1}
```

which gives the following error
*positional operator '.$' couldn't find a matching element in the array*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to this [How to retrieve all matching elements present inside array in Mongo DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429243/how-to-retrieve-all-matching-elements-present-inside-array-in-mongo-db)

i had to use aggregations.

```
stage 1 : $match : {
$or:[{"timeSlot.startTime":{$lt: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gt: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endDate":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }]
  
}

stage 2 : $unwind: {
  path: "$timeSlot",
  includeArrayIndex: 'string',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}

stage 3 : $match: {
$or:[{"timeSlot.startTime":{$lt: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endTime":{$gt: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")} }, {"timeSlot.startTime":{$gte: Date("2021-09-20T09:55:00.000Z")}, "timeSlot.endDate":{$lte: Date("2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z")} }]
  
}

stage 4 : $group : {
  _id: "$_id",
  timeSlot: {
    $addToSet: "$timeSlot"
  }
}
```

which will produce...

```
_id:61489523a764fdc7844eb362
timeSlot:Array
0:Object
startTime:2021-09-20T07:00:00.000+00:00
_id:6148a6a1bb84ebf378ce09c4
endTime:2021-09-20T10:00:00.000+00:00
1:Object
startTime:2021-09-20T07:00:00.000+00:00
endTime:2021-09-20T10:00:00.000+00:00
_id:6148af71bb84ebf378ce09c6
```